# c# Registry Unable to Create a SubKey

Tags: c#, registry

I couldn't create a subkey under the following Path :

```
Registry.CurrentUser + @"\Software\";
```

I tried that using the following code :

```
       RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").CreateSubKey("MyKey");
        Key.SetValue("Check","Yes");
```

Cannot write : `Cannot write to the registry key.`

I also tried to open the application with the admin privileges , but it still display the same error.

**Please note that i can create subkeys in Registry.CurrentUser without admin privileges ,And I Have the Permission Read/Full Control on the Both Paths (Current User and SOFTWARE)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because according to MSDN, `OpenSubKey` retrieves a subkey as read-only. Instead, try to use `OpenSubKey(name, true)`. In this code, `true` means I need write access to the key. For more information check this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx) out.

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining why `OpenSubKey(name, true)` works, and maybe providing a link to the MSDN page for each of the two method overloads.